# Xamarin DataTable Add New Row

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, datatable

I'm actually working on an app with Xamarin and I want to use DataTable to communicate with my Web Service.

But I can't deserialize the received JSON with JSON.NET library. After many research, I discovered that I can't use method DataTable.NewRow(). I have an error:

```
Reference to type 'MarshalByValueComponent' claims it is defined in 'System', but it could not be found
```

I want to know how to solve this Error.

I have tried on a new Xamarin solution but it still not working.

I'm on Visual Studio 15.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would really recommend against trying to use DataTable in a mobile project.  There are much better and lightweight solutions available

Comment: Have you an example of a better solutions to use ?

Comment: Yes.  Just serialize C# objects

Comment: In my case, I can't, I don't know how many property I will have. So, I can't use object. I actually use a list<dictionary<string, object>> for replace DataTable but it's not a good solution

Comment: Also having this problem... What other controls could we use instead of a data table?